# Playing a video and live recording another video on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: pulseaudio, audio-jack, video-recording

My lecture goes on for 4 hours daily on Zoom and i use OBS Studio to record them.The problem is i can't play any other audio/video file simultaneously as long as i'm recording the lecture.If i play any other audio then the sound of lecture conflicts with the sound of say a song that i playing but my recording from OBS studio does not get affected which is a good thing.

So is it possible to play any song or watch youtube simultaneously while recording a live video using OBS studio...?
My lectures are streaming live on Zoom.Yes i can only watch them live for as long as they are streaming live (4-5 hours daily)

I don't think i can run obs studio + zoom in virtual machine and do any other stuff on my host machine.This will be too much for my system i guess as i only have 8 gb of Ram so i'll prefer a solution which uses my host machine.

Something to do with my earphone jack would be right i guess. Like if i have the choice to prioritize on which software i want sound and which software to mute.I can't mute the sound as that would also mute the sound in my recording but i also don't want to conflict with other videos that i'm playing simultaneously. I guess you guys got my point.

I don't know obs is the best option to record from zoom but it does the job perfectly.

Comment: Better stick with the zoom lecture than diverting yourself with music of video ;) (joke) Still I am surprised it would not work: with pulseaudio, you should be able to play multiple sources: your browser and other audio sources. And OBS "Desktop Audio" just records whatever is playing.

Comment: I can play multiple sources but the thing is livestream's audio and youtube's audio conflict with each other.

Comment: OBS is capturing the sound card, so anything you play will be recorded as well.

Comment: Well that's not the case here. OBS is capturing a specific window or source for example Zoom in my case.If i play anything in youtube, it's not recorded by OBS but the sound from Zoom and Youtube conflicts.